# Nested subquery within a case statement returning null

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a nested sql subquery that returns one value from the original table if year value in the datetime column isn't 1799, and return the max value from another column in another table if the value is 1799.  I know I'm probably doing something stupid, but I'm only getting NULL in the 'logofftime' column when I should be getting the date.  Here is a simple version of my code:

```
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN year(us.logofftime) = '1799' 
 THEN
                (SELECT max(ua.time)
                FROM useractivity ua
                WHERE ua.usersessionid = us.usersessionid)
        ELSE us.logofftime
        END) AS logofftime,
                    us.operatingsystem, us.country, 
                    us.source, us.logoffmethod 
FROM    UserSession us
WHERE us.logontime > '2017-07-01'
AND us.clientid = '12455';
```

EDIT : I've added the last two lines to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a lot of `NULL` values for `logofftime` -- if the value is `NULL`, the result will be `NULL`.

So, perhaps you intend to replace those values as well:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN year(us.logofftime) = 1799 OR us.logofftime IS NULL
             THEN (SELECT max(ua.time)
                   FROM useractivity ua
                   WHERE ua.usersessionid = us.usersessionid
                  )
             ELSE us.logofftime
        END) AS logofftime,
      us.operatingsystem, us.country, 
       us.source, us.logoffmethod 
FROM UserSession us;
```

Comment: That's the thing, there are no null values in either table, so I would think that the original query would work, but I'll give the query you posted a go.

Comment: As an edit to the above comment, that query still returns null values.  I've also edited my original post to include an additional where clause at the end of the query.